# If exist coexistence with left join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code which I want to use inside left join:

```
Left join
    (IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblGLUserAccess WHERE table_name ='test')  
           select 1 else select 2
    )
```

This is important since it's a long query.

Comment: Regardless the correct solution from @forpas, if you provide us the complete query a better solution may be devised :-)

Comment: `code`
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE
WHEN EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A' ) THEN
 SELECT q23.MRID , q23.NTP FROM ( SELECT MRID, NSIA4 NTP FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co
 UNION SELECT MRID, CASE WHEN a.NBR = 0 then NTPSERV END NTP FROM TABLE_C a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co) q23
ELSE SELECT q23.MRID , q23.NTP from ( SELECT MRID, CASE WHEN a.NBR = 0 then NTPSERV END NTP FROM TABLE_C a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co) q23
END ) q24 ON q0.MRID = q24.MRID

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Already created new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098531/trying-to-use-where-exist-under-left-join

Answer (score 1):

You must have the SELECT statement first and then a CASE statement to choose the proper value:

```
Left join
(
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblGLUserAccess WHERE table_name ='test') THEN 1 
      ELSE 2
    END AS columnname
)
```

Comment: Hello, i tried but still giving error.
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE
WHEN EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A' ) THEN
 SELECT q23.MRID , q23.NTP FROM ( SELECT MRID, NSIA4 NTP FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co
 UNION SELECT MRID, CASE WHEN a.NBR = 0 then NTPSERV END NTP FROM TABLE_C a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co) q23
ELSE SELECT q23.MRID , q23.NTP from ( SELECT MRID, CASE WHEN a.NBR = 0 then NTPSERV END NTP FROM TABLE_C a, TABLE_B b WHERE a.obj = b.co) q23
END ) q24 ON q0.MRID = q24.MRID

Comment: My answer is about the code you posted in your question. If you have other problems with your query post another question with the full code of your query with sample data and expected results.